# A 'documentation coverage' of grunt-ngdocs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngdoc

To generate the documentation of my project I use ng-docs:

https://github.com/m7r/grunt-ngdocs

I would like to have a report of which elements (controllers, directives,...) are not yet documented using grunt-ngdocs.

Ideally this report could be added directly into the documentation, or in a way to locate easily the files which are missing documentation. Does such a grunt task or plugin exist?

Comment: Hello miguelr,
have you found a solution? I have seen you have a very similar requirement to mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627055/jscs-checks-for-ngdocs

Comment: cilap, nothing so far other than checking the files manually. Still hope to find a way!

Comment: We have found this, but it is for jsdoc https://github.com/jscs-dev/jscs-jsdoc. Not sure if it will even work with ngdocs