# JSCS checks for ngdocs?

Tags: jscs, ngdoc

Wondering if there are any JSCS checks for ngdocs?

Alternatively which documentation framework do you suggest for AngularJS code and the possibility to check if code is documented well?

maybe related to this: [A 'documentation coverage' of grunt-ngdocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176956/a-documentation-coverage-of-grunt-ngdocs)

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get this working with the following .jscsrc:

`{
  "preset": "google",
  "maximumLineLength": 120,
  "disallowMultipleVarDecl": false,
  "jsDoc": {
    "checkAnnotations": {
      "preset": "jsdoc3",
      "extra": {
        "ngdoc": "some",
        "methodOf": "some"
      }
    }
  }
}`

You may need to add more entries to the `extra` section for the tags you use.

Comment: GavD_UK: We are using your suggestion, this ruleset is ignoring missing documentation. If we enable "enforceExistence" option, jscs will complain that about missing documentation for the compile function. This function is already documented by angular, it doesn't need any extra documentation from us. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'd have to see your project - are you sure you're only applying jscs to your project, and not your dependencies/node_modules etc?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this issue](https://github.com/jscs-dev/jscs-jsdoc/issues/151) on jscs-jsdoc. I cann't help with a documentation framework for Angular, but I guess should be fine grunt-ngdocs